# Average Size of an RSS/Feed file, for Data Storage and Bandwidth Calculation

Tags: rss, monitoring, feed, web-crawler

Doing a back of the envelope calculation to determine network bandwidth and data storage needed to monitor approx 10,00,000 feeds every 20 minutes.

Any idea what could be the average size of an rss file ?

I remember reading somewhere the guys from technorati revealing the avg size of an rss file.

Ankur Gupta

Answer (score 4):

If feeds are served properly, you don't need to download them in order to check for changes.

Just send appropriate `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` header, and if feed hasn't changed, you'll receive only HTTP status 304 response, with no body.

Comment: Thanks porneL ... was unaware about these headers ... would save me ton's of bandwidth.